# How to put white space after a letter while typing with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, space

I want to put empty spaces after a letter while typing.

We can make it with css `letter-spacing` property but when we copy this text, i does not keep white spaces.

**How can we make it with vanilla javascript?**

*Added letter-spacing to my css to show what i want exaclty.*

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wkw72u7e/)**

```js
var my_text = document.getElementById("my_text");
var output_text = document.getElementById("output_text");

my_text.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var val = this.value;
  output_text.innerHTML = val;
});
```

```css
#output_text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="my_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div id="output_text"></div>
```

Comment: You want the spaces to be added in the input area or in a different element, like you did in the snippet?

Comment: I want spaces to be added just to output area @trincot

Comment: Matansh has answered well. Just use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, since it needs to treat `&` and `<` literally. Also, the `input` event is more useful than `keyup`

Comment: Tried textContent also but anyway, answer is well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @trincot. I changed in the fiddle from innerHTML to textContent, and I don't see any difference. Can you explain what suppose to be the difference?

Comment: Indeed, browsers are forgiving, and as there are spaces after every character, it always works out well with `innerHTML`, but a literal `<` should really be encoded as `&lt;` when used in HTML encoding. In text encoding (`textContent`) no such encoding is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split all the characters and join with a white space: https://jsfiddle.net/wkw72u7e/4/.

```
var my_text = document.getElementById("my_text");
var output_text = document.getElementById("output_text");

my_text.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  output_text.innerHTML = this.value.split('').join(' ');
});


#output_text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Can we expand white space area?

Comment: Yes. You can change the join input from ' ' to &nbsp;. One &nbsp; is one white space, just insert as much as you want (f.e. this.value.split('').join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;') suppose to be equivalent to 4 whitespaces).

Comment: By the way, if you are satisfied with the answer, I would really appreciate it if you will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

And why vanilla javascript? Ordinary javascript can do it:

```js
var my_text = document.getElementById("my_text");
var output_text = document.getElementById("output_text");

my_text.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  output_text.innerHTML += " " + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
});
```

```css
#output_text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="my_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div id="output_text"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the word [*vanilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) in this context.